# Repository method accepting predicate and orderby

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I’ve set up a repository with Entity Framework and have the following interface method:

```cs
Task<IList<Person>> SearchForPeople(Expression<Func<Person, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<Person, object>> orderBy);
```

It’s fairly basic, and I’ve implemented it as:

```cs
public async Task<IList<Person>> SearchForPeople(Expression<Func<Person, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<Person, object>> orderBy)
{
    return await this.context.People.Where(predicate).OrderBy(orderBy).ToListAsync();
}
```

I’m currently calling it like this:

```cs
var people = await repository.SearchForPeople(x => x.Born.Day == now.Day && x.Born.Month == now.Month, x => x.OrderingKey);
```

Which returns all the people whose birthdays fall on the specified day/month, and then orders them according to a property called "orderingKey" which is essentially their name concatenated.

This works fine, but if I try to change the orderby to something like this:

```cs
var people = await repository.SearchForPeople(x => x.Born.Day == now.Day && x.Born.Month == now.Month, x => x.Born);
```

I get an error saying that I cannot cast System.DateTime to System.Object. I understand why this is happening as I’ve clearly stated that the orderby property should be of type “object”, but I cannot see how to rewrite this so that my orderby accepts any type of property to orderby without rewriting the whole thing using the generic T, which I don’t really want to do as I don’t want a generic repository just a generic filter!

Is there another way of making both types of orderby work?

Comment: You can make the single method generic: `Task<IList<Person>> SearchForPeople<T>(...Expression<Func<Person, T>>...)`, but in my experience it's better just to return IQueryable from your repository if your caller needs this kind of granular control, otherwise you just end up rewriting the entire Linq syntax.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. I Was originally returning IQueryable, but after changing the method to be async I couldn’t find a suitable *Async() method that would allow me to return the data after applying Where and OrderBy. Settled for ToListAsync() and changed the return type to suit. Any ideas?

Comment: If you returned IQueryable, your caller would then use: `await repository.SearchForPeople().Select(/* Project Here */).ToListAsync()`. So instead of your Repository initializing the asynchronous part, your caller would. But hey, it's all a matter of what works for your project!

Comment: Ah, I see. I’m trying to keep as much of that logic as possible in the repository, so I think I’ll stick with your first suggestion. If you want to write it as an answer, I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make just that method generic:

```
public async Task<IList<Person>> SearchForPeople<T>(Expression<Func<Person, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<Person, T>> orderBy)
{
    return await this.context.People.Where(predicate).OrderBy(orderBy).ToListAsync();
}
```

Then using type inference, the following should work:

```
var people = await repository.SearchForPeople(x => x.Born.Day == now.Day && x.Born.Month == now.Month, x => x.Born);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public async Task<IList<Person>> SearchForPeople<TOrderKey>(Expression<Func<Person, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<Person, TOrderKey>> orderBy)
{
    return await this.context.People.Where(predicate).OrderBy(orderBy).ToListAsync();
}
```

Instead of passing in "Object" you define it as a generic parameter.